# JSON object date ascending

Tags: javascript, json

I have this object, the exmalpe shown is only a small sample of the full object, that I need sorting on date ascending order in javascript.

```
{
"2009-07-31T00:00:00.000Z": -4.9287,
"2008-11-30T00:00:00.000Z": 4.917,
"2011-07-31T00:00:00.000Z": 6.0647,
"2008-06-30T00:00:00.000Z": 6.1647,
"2013-06-30T00:00:00.000Z": -1.1205,
"2012-01-31T00:00:00.000Z": 3.325,
"2010-07-31T00:00:00.000Z": -1.6741,
"2015-10-31T00:00:00.000Z": -6.6224,
"2010-08-31T00:00:00.000Z": 7.607,
"2005-08-31T00:00:00.000Z": -1.6419,
"2014-06-30T00:00:00.000Z": 2.6802,
"2009-03-31T00:00:00.000Z": -7.5287,
"2006-06-30T00:00:00.000Z": -3.4553,
"2011-12-31T00:00:00.000Z": 4.8374,
}
```

How would I go about doing it?

Comment: you can not sort the properties of an object. you can take just the keys in an array and sort them and take it as a reference for later use.

Comment: Once you do that, I think natural string sort order will suffice.